# Arduino nano and wemos sd shield

Tags: arduino-nano, sd-card

Is it possible use Arduino nano with wemos sd shield? If I can, how to I connect sd shield to arduino and what modification I need to do on library setting?

Comment: What's a Wemos SD shield?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you can't. The WeMos boards operate at 3.3V, and so does the SD card. If you want to use a 5V Arduino with a 3.3V SD card, you'll need voltage level shifters.

The schematic of the WeMos SD shield will tell you what SD connections go to what pins. Then just google how to use an SD card with Arduino to connect those pins to the correct Arduino pins.